# Moving from TWiki to SharepointWiki (or WikiPlus)

Tags: sharepoint, migration

Does anyone know of a tool or easy way to migrate from TWiki (latest version) to Sharepoint's built-in Wiki?

Comment: why  are you moving from twiki to sharepoing wiki ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration of content into SharePoint in general is difficult. Unless you have development resources I think you're on the right track with using a tool. You can find several by searching for `sharepoint migration tool`.

You might also like to read [this blog post](http://www.workshares.co.uk/blog/2009/07/migrate-or-move-content-inside-sharepoint/) by Andrew Walmsley that describes the issues to consider.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a crack at this some time, and it's been used a lot with some success. It's not nice, but it works. https://sites.google.com/site/sharepointwikiuploader/

Answer (score 2):

I've been a core developer for TWiki and Foswiki since about 2002, but in the interests of interoperability (and because I've been asked for it) I sat down and wrote a windows application that can be used to import TWiki's and Foswiki's to Sharepoint.

You can find more at http://inkchilli.com - it imports to sharepoint 2007, 2010, 2012 and office 365.

Sven